# Having issues with a line break on :after pseudo element

Tags: html, css

I built a call-to-action lower sticky bar using css and overriding a default theme footer id. This sticky bar has 3 columns; Phone icon and "call" text, Dialogue bubble and "text us", and an exam button with a calendar icon and "Free exam" text. Here is the MOBILE css I used to center the text under each icon.

```
.fa.fa-phone:after {
content:"\A CALL";
color:#666;
white-space:pre;
font-size:10px;
font-family:arial;
font-weight:700;
}
```

Which generates this:

[image]

I received another request to add this same type of bar on a different site. So again, I added the same code as above, just changing the icon type and content text to "Tulsa Sales" but instead of a line break, it just places the text to the right of the icon.

I used this for the new site:

```
.x-icon.tulsaphone:after {
content:"\a  TULSA \a SALES";
color:#fff;
white-space:pre;
font-size:8px;
font-family:arial;
font-weight:700;
}
```

[image]

I'm at my wits end because I thought adding \a "content here" and white-space:pre; would give me the proper line break I was looking for on mobile devices.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Site with functioning buttons: coopermisnerortho.com

Site with non-function buttons: whistlerbillboards.com

Answer (score 0):

You could make the `:after` a `block` element.

```
.x-icon.tulsaphone:after {
    display: block;
    content:"TULSA \a SALES";
    color:#fff;
    white-space:pre;
    font-size:8px;
    font-family:arial;
    font-weight:700;
}
```

Or use `flexbox` to stack the children

```
.x-icon.tulsaphone {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.x-icon.tulsaphone:after {
  content: "TULSA \a SALES";
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 8px;
  font-family: arial;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate the reply, unfortunately neither option worked.

Comment: Can you create an example with a snippet here or a JSFIddle or something like that

Comment: Sure thing, here you go. https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=6xfJimO6vi On here it appears to drop the text exactly like I'm intending for it to do.

Comment: I am so sorry! Here you go. https://jsfiddle.net/mcztL1hb/

Comment: The icons didn't load, but check this https://jsfiddle.net/7chepkdL/